# Javascript function is not working with onmouseover attribute

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I want to change css property when mouse is over/out on images. Unfortunately, it didn't seem to work, so I tested simple javascript with onmouseover attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_alert() { document.alert("Alert"); }
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="test" onmouseover="show_alert()">
  ....
</div>
```

but when I moved mouse over this div block, nothing happened and kinda hard to debug
what was going inside. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: btw, `document` as no property called `alert`. It's `window.alert()`! or simply `alert('hello');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alert` method is a method of the `window` object, not the `document` object. Using `document.alert` returns `undefined`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_alert() { window.alert("Alert"); }
</script>
```

Comment: I think `document.alert()` returns a reference error rather than `undefined`.

Comment: @Teemu: No, it *causes* a reference error, because you are trying to use `undefined` as a function. `document.alert` returns `undefined`, and calling `undefined()` causes an error.

Answer (score 3):

The alert doesn't work because you're using `document.alert`, which doesn't exist. You'll be wanting `window.alert`, or just `alert`

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VL9/)

Comment: ugh.. that was correct. what if I want to change some css in function? should i still use window instead document? cuz document.getElementById doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change css property when mouse is over/out on images

why do you need javascript for this? A simple CSS Style does the trick:

```
img:hover { border: 2px solid red; }
```

**By the way**

`document` as no property called `alert`. It's `window.alert()`! or simply `alert('hello');`

Comment: I doubt this is proper in my case because I want to hide/show some text corresponding to each image by mouseover/out. So when mouse is over a certain image, I want to show a div id block for that image.